# Passing BraintreeJS paymentnonce payload to ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, braintree

I'm trying to integrate Chargebee with Braintree using ChargeBee's API+BraintreeJS (easiest to get PCI compliance). Here is the link of methods that could be used (https://www.chargebee.com/docs/braintree.html). Based on that document, I can conclude that these are the steps

1) Generate clientToken using Braintree SDK for .NET
2) Use BraintreeJS to tokenize all hosted fields and send to Braintree API to get payment nonce
3) Use ChargeBee SDK for .NET and send payment nonce to create subscription in ChargeBee

I've managed to do (1) and (2) but my issue is how could I read the payment nonce during postback? I've tried using controller but still getting null value

Here's my code

```js
<script>
    var form = document.querySelector('#cardForm');
    var authorization = '<%=clientToken%>';

    braintree.client.create({
        authorization: authorization
    }, function (err, clientInstance) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        createHostedFields(clientInstance);
    });

    function createHostedFields(clientInstance) {
        braintree.hostedFields.create({
            client: clientInstance,
            styles: {
                'input': {
                    'font-size': '16px',
                    'font-family': 'courier, monospace',
                    'font-weight': 'lighter',
                    'color': '#ccc'
                },
                ':focus': {
                    'color': 'black'
                },
                '.valid': {
                    'color': '#8bdda8'
                }
            },
            fields: {
                number: {
                    selector: '#card-number',
                    placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'
                },
                cvv: {
                    selector: '#cvv',
                    placeholder: '123'
                },
                expirationDate: {
                    selector: '#expiration-date',
                    placeholder: 'MM/YYYY'
                },
                postalCode: {
                    selector: '#postal-code',
                    placeholder: '11111'
                }
            }
        }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {
            if (hostedFieldsErr) {
                console.error(hostedFieldsErr);
                return;
            }

            submit.removeAttribute('disabled');

            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
                    if (tokenizeErr) {
                        console.error(tokenizeErr);
                        return;
                    }

                    // If this was a real integration, this is where you would
                    // send the nonce to your server.
                    var noncestr = payload.nonce
                    alert(noncestr); // Confirm nonce is received.

                    console.log('Got a nonce: ' + payload.nonce);
                    $('#paymentmethodnonce').attr("value", noncestr); // Add nonce to form element.
                    form.submit();
                });
                
            }, false);
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="demo-frame">
        <form action="/" method="post" id="cardForm">
            <label class="hosted-fields--label" for="card-number">Card Number</label>
            <div id="card-number" class="hosted-field"></div>

            <label class="hosted-fields--label" for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
            <div id="expiration-date" class="hosted-field"></div>

            <label class="hosted-fields--label" for="cvv">CVV</label>
            <div id="cvv" class="hosted-field"></div>

            <label class="hosted-fields--label" for="postal-code">Postal Code</label>
            <div id="postal-code" class="hosted-field"></div>

            <div class="button-container">
                <input type="submit" class="button button--small button--green" value="Purchase" id="submit" />
            </div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult"></asp:Label>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.8.0/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.8.0/js/hosted-fields.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string clientToken;
    private BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway
    {
        Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
        MerchantId = "xxx",
        PublicKey = "xxx",
        PrivateKey = "xxx"

    };
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //generate clienttoken from braintree sdk
            clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.generate();
        }
        else
        {
            var paymentnonce = Request.Form["paymentmethodnonce"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The callback that you pass to `hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize` uses a [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find an element with ID `paymentmethodnonce` and store the generated nonce inside of it. However, there's no element with that ID in the HTML that you submitted. Based on the HTML you've shared, that call should fail, and your subsequent attempt to retrieve `paymentmethodnonce` using `Request.Form` will also fail.

You should be able to solve this by adding a hidden input element to your form with the id `paymentmethodnonce`.

```
<input type="hidden" id="paymentmethodnonce" />
```

This will give your `tokenize` callback a place to put the nonce, and it will make the nonce part of the form, which should allow your `Request.Form` to retrieve it successfully.

Comment: Thanks. I've added it. The issue here is that my submit doesn't do a PostBack. any clue?

Comment: @mraswinc: I can't offer a great explanation, but I've found it necessary to run [`ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference(v=vs.110).aspx) before checking `IsPostBack` in my own integrations. This call should set up the postback event so that you can check for it properly.